# Port Forwarding/Port Trigger on DLink DIR 600M

Tags: port-forwarding

I have searched all over internet for Port Triggering help but always got results for port forwarding. In fact I need to Port Forward my router (DLink Wireless N 150 HOme Router Model : DIR-600M) to the wamp server that listens to the port 8808 on a particular IP say : 192.168.1.152.

But my router only has options Port Triggering. Can we do port forwarding using this? or does "virtual server" works?

Can anyone please help